# Setting up a new palette() in R: need to call palette(rainbow(N)) twice

Tags: r

I drawing plots within a loop, and every plot needs a new palette according to the number of elements in the plot.

I'm puzzled by the fact that palette(rainbow(i)) does not have an immediate effect. Instead, I have to call it twice.

For instance, this does not work:

```
for(i in 10:20){
    colors <- palette(rainbow(i))
    if (i !=length(colors)){cat("\nNumber of colors does not match", 
                                i,"-",  length(colors))}
}

Number of colors does not match 10 - 20
Number of colors does not match 11 - 10
Number of colors does not match 12 - 11
Number of colors does not match 13 - 12
Number of colors does not match 14 - 13
Number of colors does not match 15 - 14
Number of colors does not match 16 - 15
Number of colors does not match 17 - 16
Number of colors does not match 18 - 17
Number of colors does not match 19 - 18
Number of colors does not match 20 - 19
```

To make sure it set up the new palette, I have to call it twice:

```
for(i in 10:20){
    colors <- palette(rainbow(i))
    colors <- palette(rainbow(i))
    if (i !=length(colors)){cat("\nNumber of colors does un match", 
                                 i,"-",  length(colors))}
}
```

Is this some bug or I'm using palette in a wrong way?

Comment: Are you aware that the return value of `palette` is the "palette which _was_ in effect"? See `?palette`.

Comment: Not indeed! I had misread that sentence. Then I have to call it twice, one to make the change and another to get the colors? (I need the new color list)

Comment: `rainbow` is more than enough to get the colors. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Argh, you are right! I have a graph of nodes (posts, comments) and need to color them by user: posts from the same user should have the same color.